# If I replace the .class file in gwt compiled war folder. Will it work?

Tags: tomcat, gwt, compilation, war, .class-file

I replaced the .class file in gwt compiled war folder after making few changes. But, after starting of project it is not showing the changes . The changes has not been reflected. What should I do so, that the changes will reflect in project.

Comment: Well if were in your place i would have done myself rather than asking on this forum.

Comment: @almasshaikh I tried my best but I didn't get any solution then only I asked it. If you know the answer please help.

Comment: are you trying to change in gwt code? it's not work. you need to compile war and create new war for every change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the GWT application is compiles, the GWT cross-compiler translates the Java application to standalone JavaScript files that are optionally obfuscated and deeply optimized.

There are two types of classes in GWT application: Serverside and Clientside.

All classes of clientside will be coverted into javascript and serverside classes into .class files

So if you are replacing client side classes into war file it will not work, but server side class will work.

Comment: Though for server side changes to be picked up you also need to reload the webapp (just a click away with DevMode's embedded server)